# How to find the level of node in binary tree in haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to find the level at which a certain node is for example if binary tree is:

(Node (Node (Node (Node Leaf Leaf 9) Leaf 8) Leaf 7) Leaf 6)

Level of 9 is 3 
Level of 8 is 2 
Level of 7 is 1 
Level of 6 is 0

Could anyone help me in this regard?

The function should be something like this:

path :: Tree a -> a -> Int

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a helper function that keeps track of the level of the tree. You thus make a helper function `path'` with signature:

```
path' :: Int -> Tree a -> a -> Int
path' level (Node left right x) query
    | … = …
    | … = …
    | otherwise = …
path' _ Leaf _ = …
```

where you need to fill in the `…` parts. You will need to make recursive calls to visit the `left` and `right` subtree, and this can be done with a call to `path'` where you call it with `(level+1)` as first parameter.

If you implemented `path'`, the `path` is just:

```
path :: Tree a -> a -> Int
path = path' 0
```

If the item is not found you will here have to return a value like `-1`, since the level of a tree is always greater than or equal to zero. It is however, as @dfeuer says, more idiomatic to work with a `Maybe Int`, and return `Nothing` in case the element is not found:

```
path' :: Int -> Tree a -> a -> Maybe Int
path' level (Node left right x) query
    | … = …
    | … = …
    | otherwise = …
path' _ Leaf _ = …

path :: Tree a -> a -> Maybe Int
path = path' 0
```

In that case, you can also make use of [**`(<|>) :: Alternative f => f a -> f a -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-) to combine the results of recursive calls, and thus remove a line in the `path'` implementation:

```
import Control.Applicative((<|>))

path' :: Int -> Tree a -> a -> Maybe Int
path' level (Node left right x) query
    | … = …
    | otherwise = … <|> …
path' _ Leaf _ = …
```

Comment: I would give `path'` (and ideally also `path`) a `Maybe Int` result (or encode `Nothing` as `-1`, but that's ugly).

Comment: @dfeuer: yes. here `-1` however is an option, since the level can not be negative. But `Maybe` is of course more idiomatic, and allows to use it with its `Monad` instance.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you elaborate a bit what would be the body of path function be if I use it with path'

Comment: I am new to Haskell don't know much about its syntax @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Abraham: but that is already in the answer, then `path = path' 0`, so we call `path'` with as first parameter `0` and all the rest of the parameters are the same.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Could you tell me what would be the base case

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what will be the output in case of leaf
path' _ Leaf _ = …

Comment: @Abraham: wel what is the level of an element in a tree that is a `Leaf`, then the element is not in the tree...